# Ignore outer grouping and only return groups which match in alternation

Tags: python, regex, grouping

I have the following regex:

```
regex = re.compile(r'(\((\d{3})\)\s*|(\d{3})-?)')
```

Essentially it includes an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and a grouping inside the alternation. I only want to consider the grouping inside the alternation: the first and second `(\d{3})` and only the one group that matches should be returned.

Given the following, here's what I expect:

```
regex.match('(123) ').groups()
```

expected:

```
('123',)
```

actual:

```
('(123) ', '123', None)
```

Comment: Make your outer group a non capturing group if you don't want to capture it.

Comment: Try using a non-capturing group for the outer grouping and filter out all `None` items. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/GHkl7n).

Comment: @cxw. Sorry about that. Rude comment rescinded. And thanks for the link.

Comment: @MadPhysicist No worries :) .  I'll move the link into the question and remove my comment for cleanup.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you. Is this supported by the Python regex engine instead of having to apply additional logic to the result? It seems like if `|` is used, only the groups that match should be returned.

Comment: @cosmos1990 No, that is not possible with `re`, but it is possible with Python PyPi regex module using a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html). See http://rextester.com/EDNRP21999.

Comment: So what's your question? Do you want explanation why you get this output? Or do you want a different regex pattern that produces the expected output?

Comment: @Rawing both :) It looks like it's been answered.

Comment: Downvotes on questions without a comment are highly discouraged. It's possible to improve the question if proper feedback is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting this

```
(\((\d{3})\)\s*|(\d{3})-?)
```

to return `123` but you have two pairs of grouping parentheses -- one beginning at the start and the other beginning before `\d`, and so you get two groups returned. If you don't want the `(123)` but you do want the `123` then the outer pair needs to be non-capturing:

```
(?:\((\d{3})\)\s*|(\d{3})-?)
```

That only solves one part of your problem. The other is that your third capturing group, that does not match anything, returns None. That can't be easily solved in the regular expression itself because for every pair of grouping parentheses in your regular expression you get something back from `match.groups()`. That is how `groups()` is defined. Consider using `filter()`:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r"(?:\((\d{3})\)\s*|(\d{3})-?)")
>>> regex.match('(123) ').groups()
('123', None)
>>> tuple(filter(None, regex.match('(123) ').groups()))
('123',)
```